# Объектно-ориентированный код в C

Tags: ооп, c

Поскольку OO - это шаблон программирования, а не неотъемлемое свойство языка, он должен быть применим и к C. Как пишут ОО-код в C, когда это нужно и когда нельзя задействовать C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, суть сказали - использовать структуры для хранения контекста конкретных объектов. И передавать соответствующую структуру аргументом в функции. Которые уже будут работать с этой структурой как с классом =3

Пример:

```
typedef struct { // контекст объекта с чем угодно внутри
    int x;
    int y;
} nya;
typedef nya * pnya;

void nya_construct (pnya this) // конструктор
{
    this->x = 0;
    this->y = 0;
}

void nya_incx (pnya this) // метод 1
{
    this->x++;
}

void nya_decy (pnya this) // метод 2
{
    this->y--;
}

int main (void) // использование
{
    pnya first = (pnya)malloc(sizeof(nya)); // объект 1
    pnya second = (pnya)malloc(sizeof(nya)); // объект 2
    nya_construct(first); // конструируем
    nya_construct(second);
    nya_incx(first); // исполняем метод в контексте объекта 1

    free(first); // удаляем. Деструктора нет, его не вызываем
    free(second);
}
```

Ну, в таком духе.

Comment: В Си нету this.

Comment: this, если вы обратите внимание, - это всего лишь параметр функции, который я так назвал по собственному желанию.
Если хотите, можно назвать его как-то иначе. Суть не в названии аргумента, а в подходе.

А то, что его подсветил редактор - это уже не я виноват =)

Comment: Щит, во я ступил. Увидел и решил что ошибка. Хотя полюбому typedef забыт =)

Comment: Да ладно, бывает =D особенно ночью =)

А, да, тайпдеф забыт ^^"

Comment: Не будет работать, т.к. в функцию в стеке будет передаваться
копия структуры.
Надо передавать указатель и писать 
(this->y)--; или (*this).y--;

Comment: Вы правы =)

Comment: не надо из С делать ОО-язык, а привязать данные к функциям как показано выше, всегда само собой получится :-)

Answer (score 3):

Ну и вопросик.
Как пишут - не знаю, объяснить тем более не смогу.
Но могу назвать классический пример - библиотека графических виджетов Tk (из известной связки Tcl/Tk).
На классику ООП весьма похоже, написано на C, исходники открыты и статей куча.
Но энтузиазм с этим знакомиться должен быть свой.

Answer (score 2):

с разной степенью гемморойности можно сделать классы
   члены класса - это члены структур.
   даже виртуальные методы можно сделать - при создании структур надо создавать в экземпляре класса указатель на область памяти например массив с указателями на функции. много ручного труда но сработает.
   вызывать деструктор при выходе из блока можно только вручную (автоматически - нет - автоматически - это когда сам компилятор вставляет такой код)

единтвенное что не могу предположить как делать это бросать исключение (конечно какой нить глобальный джамп написать можно, но кто при этом ресурсы будет освобождать - проблема).

Comment: не могу сказать, чтобы приходилось много подобного реализовывать, но приходится плотно пользоваться COM. так вот, в нем объекты ведут счетик ссылок и сами отвечают за свое уничтожение :)

да и исключения кое-как работают.

Answer (score 2):

У меня был случай, когда писался ОО-код на C. Делался WDM драйвер. Для драйвера возможен только C-код. Драйвер был для звука на основе AC-Link. Поскольку есть много разных кодеков, а набор используемых методов очень близок, то была реализован упрощенный COM-подобный интерфейс. Вся реализация строилась на структурах подобного типа

```
struct SomeType {
    void *pContext;
    void (*pFunc)(void *pContext);
};
```

где pContext - это укатель на экземпляр структуры.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказал metazet, можно частично следовать ООП, используя структуры и функции с параметром this. Однако, это будет лишь поверхностная имитация. Наследование будет трудно реализовать и выглядеть это будет страшненько.

Answer (score 1):

В таком случае нужно обязательно посмотреть библиотеку Gtk. Написана на Си, но при этом объектно-ориентированная. Следующие три страницы помогут разобраться: [1](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/stable/chapter-gtype.html), [2](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/stable/chapter-gobject.html), [3](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/stable/chapter-signal.html).

Answer (score -1):

Есть классы и структуры. Классы по дефолту - private, а структуры - public. Используя структуры можно писать те же классы, только кода будет на пару строчек больше... Ну и с освобождением памяти нужно будет чуть больше повозиться. Кажется нигде не наврал :)

Comment: Вы что-то путаете ;).
В C проблема не столько в отсутствии слова class, которое, как Вы верно заметили, в C++ с лёгкостью заменяется словом struct и дописыванием private там, где надо, а, скорее в отсутствии ООП на уровне языка.

Comment: Может и не наврал, но вопрос был про C, а не про C++. Так что классы и методы в структурах - это не здесь.

Answer (score -2):

Назад к истокам?! :) Читайте про "C с классами" и "Objective C".